# Django CSS files are missing while deploying using IIS

Tags: django, iis

I need your assistance. I am deploying Django app on Windows Server 2019. And This went perfectly but CSS files are missing.
This the path of my application: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp. And the static folder is under myapp. I added virtual directory in IIS manager and it is set as below:
in Alias: static
in Physical path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\static

please any assist?

Comment: did you use the command `python manage.py collectstatic` ?

Comment: Yes I did but still not working. I think the issue is the path that I do not know how to define it

Comment: How did you deploy the Django project to IIS? For information about "Configure Python web apps for IIS", you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thank you! Now I managed to deploy the application.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you need to add a `web.config` file in your static files directory ( `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\static`) to bypass the `FastCGI` handler, so that these files are served as static files.

`web.config`

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- this configuration overrides the FastCGI handler to let IIS serve the static files -->
    <handlers>
    <clear/>
      <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```